# spring annotation getter for isMethod

Tags: java, el

I want to use an is method in my bean instead of a getIsmethod.  Is there a way to tell el that the method to use isn't a get method?

```
private boolean isSloAdmin = false;

//todo be nice to have it standard isMethod call
public boolean getIsSloAdmin() {
    return isSloAdmin;
}
```

Then the EL code is

${myForm.isSloAdmin}

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't have anything to do with Spring. The **standard** convention for a boolean getter is to use a method starting with `is`. So your method should be

```
public boolean isSloAdmin() {
    return isSloAdmin;
}
```

And you should access it using the JSP EL like any other bean property:

```
${myForm.sloAdmin}
```

Comment: If the field name is `isSloAdmin`, shouldn't the correct getter name be `isIsSloAdmin` and the JSP EL `${myForm.isSloAdmin}`?

Comment: isSloAdmin is a **private** field. Its name is an implementation detail. The JSP EL doesn't care about it. It could even not exist at all. All the JSP EL cares about are the public JavaBean properties, i.e. the getters (and setters, if needed). But I would name the field `sloAdmin`, not `isSloAdmin`.

Comment: I decided to make two method isSloAdmin and getIsSloAdmin so that the jsp EL reads better.  ${myForm.isSloAdmin} then works.  Thanks for the comments.  ${myForm.sloAdmin} also works as pointed out I just don't think it reads as well.